# Find all ordered pairs (m.n) of natural numbers that satisfy the equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all ordered pairs $(m, n)$ of natural numbers that satisfy the equation

> $9^m +3^m-2 = 2 p^n$

Where $p$ is a prime number.

This is what I have tried. I wrote the equation as
$ (3^m+2)(3^m-1) = 2p^n$

$(3^m-1)$ is always even and $(3^m+2)$ is  always odd. So $p$ cannot be even i.e. $p$ cannot be $2$.

When $(3^m-1) = 2 \implies m = 1.$ Then $p=5$ and $n=1$. $(1,1)$ is one ordered pair.

I feel there are no other solutions but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help?

Comment: I think, you've just proved that there is a unique solution.

Comment: How is it? can you explain?

Comment: $3^m-1$ need not be only 2 but it can be any number which is twice of a prime number, p. Say when m=3, $3^m-1$ = 26 = 2*13. In this case $3^m+2$ is not 13 or any power of 13. so, m=3 is not a solution. How to prove that for not other value of m, the equation is true?

Answer (score 5):

If there is any other solution, where m is not equal to 1 then observe that both factors necessarily have gcd as $p^k$ where k is a positive integer. But this is impossible since their difference is 3. Since  you showed uniquness for m=1, you are done.